# Wordpress - get tags from specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to get wordpress tags from specific category. For example, I have a subpage with posts from a specific category and I would like to display the tags that are available on that page. Is it possible?

I think this code might be useful:

```
<?php
        query_posts('category_name=Anime cartoon');
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
           if( get_the_tag_list() ){
              echo get_the_tag_list('</li><li>');
           }
        endwhile; endif; 
        wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
```

Only that this code shows all tags from each post separately, and I would like them not to be repeated

Display tags avaiable at specific page

Comment: `tags` do not page specific things, `tags` are connected to **posts** only, so maybe you're looking for the wrong things or you need to change the implementation methods.

Comment: Genius...That's what I'm asking. I don't know wordpress and PHP very well, I'm more frontend. And the code, as I wrote above, "may be useful" - for someone who wants to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are asking is possible!

However, the pages themselves aren't connected to anything in terms of tags. Like the comment above states, the tags are taxonomies for post only, whether that is a custom post type or not.

If you are wanting tags from a specific category that is on a specific page, one way to do it is to customize your permalinks so that the post category page urls are something like "https://yourwebsite.com/post-category/category/". From there you can get the current slug(the category), then loop through the posts within that category and get the tags that are associated.